# Label movement upon focus and unfocus

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to figure out how to make the label show inside of the textbox and move the label to the perimeter. An example of exactly how I want this is the login screen of https://www.discover.com/ When you click inside the user id or password box you will see the label adjust as you focus in and out.

https://jsfiddle.net/bobrierton/Ls1c4fdj/

```
<div class="input-wrapper userid-wrapper">
    <label for="userid-content" class="user-id-label">User ID</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control userid user-id-input" name="userID" id="userid-content" aria-required="true" data-toggle="popover" data-content="Please enter your User ID" maxlength="16" />
</div>
<div class="input-wrapper password-wrapper">
    <label for="password-content" class="password-label">Password</label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control password password-input" name="password" id="password-content" aria-required="true" data-toggle="popover" data-content="Please enter your Password" maxlength="32"/>
</div>
```

Will someone please assist me in how they are able to move the label like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach...

1. Set the label to `position: absolute` which takes it out of the document flow, and nicely places it inside the `input`.
2. Give the `input` some space using `margin`, to allow room for the label to move into.
3. Take advantage of `:focus-within`. When the `input` has `focus` the label can be targetted.
4. Set the `label` to do what you need. In the example below I have reduced font-size and repositioned it based on the sample in your question.

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sol_b/ujv0h34p/1/)

```css
.input-wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

.input-wrapper label {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 1em;
  transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  top: 0;
}

.input-wrapper input {
  margin: 1em;
}

.input-wrapper:focus-within label {
  font-size: .8em;
  top: -1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="input-wrapper userid-wrapper">
  <label for="userid-content" class="user-id-label">User ID</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control userid user-id-input" name="userID" id="userid-content" aria-required="true" data-toggle="popover" data-content="Please enter your User ID" maxlength="16" />
</div>
<div class="input-wrapper password-wrapper">
  <label for="password-content" class="password-label">Password</label>
  <input type="password" class="form-control password password-input" name="password" id="password-content" aria-required="true" data-toggle="popover" data-content="Please enter your Password" maxlength="32" />
</div>
```